# How to manipulate form input values in a dynamic form with a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with dynamically added rows that have different properties for dynamic use, submit, etc. I have one input box with a auto-complete function that has to change the rest of the input boxes values. How can change their values without a fixed `name`, `id` or `class`?

The dynamically created row:

```
<tr>
  <div id="1">
    <div id="2">
      <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="input1" />
    </div>
    <div id="3">
      <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" class="input2" onkeyup="foo(this);"/>
    </div>
  </div>   
  <input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" class="input3" />
  <input type="text" name="input4" id="input4" class="input4" />
</tr>
```

The JavaScript function:

```
foo(node){
   //node.name is input2
   change input1.value;
   change input3.value;
   change input4.value;

};
```

I can´t rely on static properties for the function, they have to be passed after the elements are created.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a solution using `row` number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible trough the DOM properties.

Example:

```
foo(elem){
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children[2].children[0].children[1].children[0].value = "";
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children[5].children[0].value = "";
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children[6].children[0].value = "";
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children[7].children[0].value = "";
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children[8].children[0].value = "";    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$(function(){
   $("#yourTable").on("keyup","INPUT",function(){
       $("INPUT").not(this).val($(this).val());
   });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b6nDX/1/

This will make **all** fields change to whatever is being typed in any of the fields **within the table**.

NOTE: You need to narrow down the selector of course, if you wish to only use one "source" field

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using jQuery and all the fields will receive different values.